# UITableView not showing Delete button on clicking minus button(Only on iOS 13)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios13

I have a table view to shows a list of items. I have implemented the default editing style delete. It's been working till iOS 12. But not on iOS 13. It does not show the Delete button when clicking the minus button.

```swift
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return machineOrders.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MachineOrderCell") as! MachineOrderCell
        let machineOrder = machineOrders[indexPath.row]

        cell.update(with: machineOrder)
        cell.decreaseQuantityButton.isEnabled = canDecreaseQuantity(for: machineOrder)
        cell.onDecreaseQuantity = {
            self.delegate.view(self, didSelectDecreaseQuantity: machineOrder)
        }
        cell.onIncreaseQuantity = {
            self.delegate.view(self, didSelectIncreaseQuantity: machineOrder)
        }

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willBeginEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneBarButton
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath?) {
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = !isCartEmpty ? (tableView.isEditing ? doneBarButton : editBarButton) : nil
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let machineOrder = machineOrders[indexPath.row]
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            self.delegate.view(self, didSelectDelete: machineOrder)
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you please add definition of minus button .

Comment: Please check my updated comment.

Comment: the minus button is the default behavior of the table view right? when setting this  tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)

Comment: “when setting this tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)” And where do you do that?

Comment: can you please check the frame of editButton.

Comment: @matt I have added a UIBarButton in the navigation bar, i am calling it on that button click. And the strangest thing is its working till iOS 12.

Comment: Make sure in your custom cell class that you only add subviews to the cell's `contentView` and not to the cell itself.

Comment: Probably unrelated to your issue but why are you messing with the `navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem` for each cell being edited? You don't need separate done and edit buttons. Use the standard `editButtonItem` provided by `UIViewController`.

Comment: @rmaddy yeah its been added in the **contentView**

Answer (score 0):

Press minus button for some seconds, I mean long press, then it will work.